# Check if the headset is inserted

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to detect whether a headset is inserted or not in my android phone, when the application is first started. Could any one suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see if AudioManager gives you the status information you're looking for:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html

Also look here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG